# A Javadoc comment with accented characters mixes blue and black color in its text on a Pandoc generated pdf. One without accented characters doesn't

Tags: java, markdown, javadoc, pandoc

Why do I have mixed colors in *Javadoc* comments when using accented characters?

This markdown:

```java
/** Première manière **/
@GetMapping
public String index() {
   return "Hello Spring Boot";
}
   
/** Deuxième manière */
@RequestMapping("/")
public String greetings() {
   return "Greetings";
}
```

produces this on a pdf, with *Pandoc*:

[image]

Blue and black colors are mixed in the middle of the text comment. Each time it encounters an accented character, here: `è`.

But without accented characters, it produces that:

[image]

Here, it's more correct, but I wonder why the whole *Javadoc* comment isn't blue?

my `header-includes` are these ones, but I have the same behavior whatever:

- I put some `one header-includes` or not,
- the *Java* code is under a citation or not,
- in a box,
- in a group

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

Is there a way to correct the behavior with accented characters? It doesn't have a nice effect.

---

@abra If I change `è` with `&egrave;`, `é` with `&eacute;` and all the characters [here](https://www.scriptol.fr/creation-site-web/accents-html.php) it produces this:

[image]

Comment: I believe you should use HTML escapes rather than embedding UTF characters yourself.

Comment: No, 99.999% of the existing tools are handling UTF-8 correctly. Do you imagine the work of thinking about replacing `é` by `\u1234`, `è` by `\u456`, `à` by `\u789`...? And their readability for humans?  What are you reading here: `\u0068\u00e9\u0020\u0021\u0020\u00e7\u0061\u0020\u0076\u0061\u0020\u003f`? And all of this for a KDE bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not specific to PDF, it also happens when converting to HTML:

```
pandoc -s test.md -o test.html
```

For [syntax highlighting](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting), pandoc uses KDE XML syntax definition files. The one for Java is
[here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/master/data/syntax/java.xml).

Download it and open it in a text editor. You will find this at line 3777:

```xml
<!-- Comment next line if you don't use Javadoc tool -->
<IncludeRules context="##Javadoc"/>
```

Do as indicated in the comment:

```xml
<!-- Comment next line if you don't use Javadoc tool -->
<!--IncludeRules context="##Javadoc"/-->
```

Now convert with your custom syntax definition file:

```
pandoc --syntax-definition=java.xml -s test.md -o test.html
```

Here is the result:

[image]